# Resolving bcrypt return promise

Tags: javascript, express, promise

Im trying to pass the result of the bcrypt hashing function into the user model below.

I can't seem be able to wrap my head around how to efficiently resolve this promise.

Heres the code:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  req.body = sanitize(req.body);

  // SHA-256
  /* const bitArray = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(req.body.data[2].value);
  const passwordHashed = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(bitArray); */

  const saltRounds = 10;

  const password = req.body.data[2].value;
  var passwordHashed;

  async function hash() {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {});
  }

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.data[0].value,
    email: req.body.data[1].value,
    password: hash(),
  });

  try {
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "Success" });
  } catch (e) {}
});
```

That is what I have tried so far, which is probably wrong

Comment: Does `bcrypt.hash(…)` even return a promise in the first place? It looks like it's accepting a callback

Comment: It does indeed accept a callback and cosole logging hash does show the desired output. But trying to assing the hash to a value outside the scope it assignes a promies and not the hash value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a callback to `bcrypt.hash` and then you can `await` it.

```js
const user = new User({
    username: req.body.data[0].value,
    email: req.body.data[1].value,
    password: await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds),
});
```

Comment: That solved it thank you. Im still trying to understand promises.

Comment: @asdasdf Glad to help.